# find patterns for alphanumeric string in a file

Tags: python

i have a file which has lines like this:

```
abcd1/klk2reg/lolba3
abcd2/klk34reg/lolba56
wxyz5/klk6reg/temp1
wxyz5/klk99reg
```

I want output like this:

```
abcd*/klk*reg/lolba*
wxyz5/klk6reg/temp1
wxyz5/klk99reg
```

words are separated by slash and each slash represents a hierarchy. so wxyz5/klk99reg and wxyz5/klk6reg/temp1 cannot be clubbed together.

Comment: What is the relation between your input and your output?

Comment: Please take the time to explain the logic behind what you're trying to do. For example why isn't `wxyz5` condensed to `wxyz*` and why aren't `klk6reg` and `klk99reg` condensed to `klk*reg`. Don't make people guess at your intentions.

Comment: @MarkMeyer . I added some more information. hopefully it will help.

Comment: @KlausD. i want to condense the lines in a file into fewer lines which have maximum common words in it and hierarchy needs to be maintained.

Comment: @rishabhagarwal show us what you have attempted so far

Comment: @Oswald - i have no idea how to solve this problem. that's why i asked here

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object for each input string, and then utilize `itertools.groupby`:

```
import re, itertools
class Path:
  def __init__(self, _path):
    self.path, self._org = _path.split('/'), _path
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.path)
  def __iter__(self):
     yield from (re.sub('\d+', '*', i) for i in self.path)
  def __eq__(self, _path_obj):
    if len(self) != len(_path_obj):
      return False
    return all(a == b for a, b in zip(self, _path_obj))
```

---

```
d = ['abcd1/klk2reg/lolba3', 'abcd2/klk34reg/lolba56', 'wxyz5/klk6reg/temp1', 'wxyz5/klk99reg']
new_data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(list(map(Path, sorted(d))))]
final_data = ['/'.join(a) if len(b) > 1 else a._org for a, b in new_data]
```

Output:

```
['abcd*/klk*reg/lolba*', 'wxyz5/klk6reg/temp1', 'wxyz5/klk99reg']
```